# Existence of infinite series for $\ln(π)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi

We all know there are lots of series representations for $π$.

But here I want to know if there exists an infinite series for $\lnπ$.

We can get obvious one from Wallis formula ( in terms of logs).

Also, I know the following series

\begin{align}
\ln(1+(7\pi/22-1)) & = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}(7\pi/22-1)^n
\end{align}

But, I want to know is there a 'simpler' one with rational terms with may be few dealable irrational terms?

Comment: Wolfram MathWorld has a long list of [pi formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html), including products.

Comment: @ Conifold I saw them earlier but doesn't fit with my need .